# Laravel adding cascade on delete to an existing table

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration, cascading-deletes

In my laravel application I have a table called researces and another one called papers. They have one-to-many relationship where each research can have one or more papers. In papers migration file I created the foreignkey constraints using:

```
        //foreign key for the research model
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('research_id');
        $table->index('researach_id');
```

Now I want to create a new migration to add cascade onDelete so that papers are deleted when their parent research is deleted. How do I do it? I'm using laravel 5.1

**EDIT**

SO the answer is very similar to the one accepted, except that I had to delete the column first and then add the foreign key. since I'm not in the production yet, so dropping the column is not a problem but if you are in a production environment you could end up messing with the consistency of data in your database. so be careful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop foreign key first then add it

```
$table->dropIndex('researach_id');
$table->foreign('research_id')
->references('id')->on('researches')
->onDelete('cascade');
```

Reference: 
[Laravel -> Database: Migrations -> Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is when i try to drop it I get Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY research_id; check that it exists (SQL: alter table papers drop foreign key research_id)

Comment: Thanks. Now I get this error 1091 Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY papers_research_id_index; check that it exists (SQL: alter table papers drop foreign key research_id)

Comment: can't I simply do $table->dropcolumn('research_id');?

Comment: Yes you can do that but then you have to create that column again

Comment: You are getting this error because you did not create a Foreign key index. You just created a normal index using  $table->index('researach_id');

Comment: I see. Ok so what do you suggest I write in the up method of the new migration? Should i delete this index and then do what?

Comment: First try this $table->dropIndex('researach_id'); then ` $table->foreign('research_id')
->references('id')->on('researches')
->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208245/discussion-between-sehdev-and-marmahan).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new migration and add the necessary foreign key constraints and also operations to be performed when the foreign key data is modified/deleted.

```php
$table->foreign('research_id')
      ->references('id')->on('researches')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Comment: So that means I have to delete this column first, then adding it as you wrote? I tried to do it but got this:  Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY `research_id`; check that it exists (SQL: alter table `papers` drop foreign key `research_id`)

Comment: Yes, you do need to drop the column if there were previous foreign key constraints set.